# ODE with inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I am wary of ODE with inequality though I do see them. I wonder whether they make some sense. For instance let us take up
$$(ydx-xdy) \ge y^2(xdx-ydy), y(1)=1$$
I want to know: how to solve (1), what could be geometrical interpretation of
the solution and what will happen if $y(1) \le (\ge) ~1$ (whether inequality is allowed in the initial value for $y(x)$). Please help.

Comment: what have you tried with just the $=$ version?

Comment: This formulation makes no sense, how do you compare differential or Pfaffian forms?

Answer (score 1):

$$(ydx-xdy) \ge y^2(xdx-ydy), y(1)=1$$
For $y \ne 0$ you have :
$$\dfrac {(ydx-xdy)}{y^2} \ge (xdx-ydy)$$
$$d \left (\dfrac {x}{y} \right ) \ge (xdx-ydy)$$
Integration gives us;

For $x>1$ we have:
$$\dfrac {2x} y \ge x^2-y^2+C$$
For $x<1$ we have:
$$\dfrac {2x} y \le x^2-y^2+C$$

Comment: Almost, except the inequality reverses direction for $x < 1$

Comment: Hi @NinadMunshi wherre did I make a mistake exactly ? Thank you

Comment: It's not a mistake, but one thing to keep in mind is that differentiation and integration in general do not preserve inequalities unless you have specific conditions. For integrating specifically you use that $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$ and $f'(x) \geq g'(x)$ to imply that $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x\geq x_0 $. What happens if you run that backwards? (Think of intersecting lines of different slopes)

Comment: Yes you're completely right  I should have integrated from 1 to x with $x >1$ @NinadMunshi Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Is this more correct @NinadMunshi

Comment: I think mentioning the domain caveat would be more correct :) but more pressingly, the inequality switch has an important bearing on the flow of the ODE

Comment: Thank you for all these informations Ninad @NinadMunshi